# Intune Mobile device and Statistics through powershell

Tags: powershell

the main question is that I need to get intune mobile devices and their statistics 
Does -getmobiledevice -results not accomplish this?

```
$Domain = $(get-addomain).dnsroot
$Log = "C:\temp\Audit\$Domain Intune Devices $(get-date -f yyyy-MM-dd).csv"

$AllDevices = Get-MobileDevice -result unlimited | Get-MobileDeviceStatistics
$AllDeviceCount = $AllDevices.count
Write-host "Mobile device count is $AllDeviceCount"
```

If possible can anyone provide me a script that can do a discovery scan of the mobile devices in Intune and their statistics.

Comment: `Get-MobileDevice -result unlimited` gives you all the registered devices, not sure what you're missing in that script - can you specify?

Comment: is there a plugin for intune like in Exchange if I am not mistaken it needs Exhchange management powershell plugin